# How to use for loop in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to insert a new field(column) to mongodb collection which has now 5246 documents. The field should be auto incremented . So that i use an for loop . My query is as follows `

```
for(i=1;i<=5246;i++) {
    db.coll.update({},{$set:{"new_field":i}},false,true)
};
```

But my bad the output is as,

```
{new_field:5246},{new_field:5246},{new_field:5246},.......
```

Is there any problem with query..?.

Comment: You sure this is Java? Doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why are you updating all records with no find criteria? Technically this loop is working as it should. What you need to do instead is loop through a cursor of your collection like so:

```
var cursor = db.coll.find(),
    i = 0;

cursor.forEach(function(x){
    db.coll.update({_id: x._id}, {$set:{new_field:i}})
    $i++;
});
```

Something like that would work instead.

Comment: Thnks fr the respnse. But what this 'row in cursor' stands for.?

Comment: @Mohammedshebin Each cursor is an object which when used like an array, in a foreach loop in most languages, will output a row which represents a row in your database. It is equal to using `forEach` on the rows. Infact you could replace the `for` for a `forEach` here.

Comment: ok. will u pls send me the exact code ..? also what u mnt by row._id ..?

Comment: @Mohammedshebin This is a simple loop, don't you know how to do loops? `row._id` is accessing the `_id` of that `row` you pull out. I have changed my code to work from the `forEach` function instead, it should work out the box.

Comment: @Mohammedshebin You cna also use the next functions as displayed here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Queries+and+Cursors

Comment: i know it. iam a bit confused here. anyway thank u.. lemme try it out.

Comment: @Mohammedshebin the dot notation on the object is the way things are accessed in the language `javascript` that you have put here and the `for` was a very basic loop of just saying that for every `row` in the `cursor` do this.